# Optimising code to find which row in an array has a monotone increment

Tags: c++, arrays

Not sure where the problem is, but my code is supposed to find which row has elements that are in monotone increment. However, when I run it, it either shows that rows aren't in increment or rows that are not in increment as one.

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main ()

    {
        int n;
        cout << "Kvadrat Matriciin irembiig oruulnuu:" << endl ;
        cin >> n;
        int M [n] [n];
        for ( int i = 1 ; i < n + 1 ; i++)
        {
            for ( int j = 1 ; j < n + 1; j++)
            {
                cout << "["<< i<< "]" << "[" << j << "]" <<" Bairshiltai Toog oruulnuu" << endl ;
                cin >> M [i] [j] ;
            }
        }
        for ( int i = 1 ; i < n + 1; i++)
        {
            bool Monotone _ Ihselt = true ;
            int min = M [i] [1] ;
            for ( int j = 1 ; Monotone _ Ihselt && j < n + 1 ; j++)
            {
                if ( min < M [i] [j] )
                min = M [i] [j] ;
            }
            Monotone _ Ihselt = min ;
            if ( Monotone _ Ihselt )
                cout << "[" << i<< "]" << "-r Mor Monotone ihselttei baina"<< endl;
            else
                cout << "Monotone ihselttei mor baihgui" << endl;

        }
    }
```

### Edit

So I made my code into this, but it's not working, as I'm not sure where to put the condition checker and it just keeps returning an error :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Kvadrat Matriciin irembiig oruulnuu:" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    int M [n] [n] ;
    for ( int i = 1 ; i < n + 1 ; i++)
    {
        for ( int j = 1 ; j < n + 1; j++)
        {
            cout << "[" << i << "]" << "[" << j << "]" << " Bairshiltai Toog oruulnuu" << endl ;
            cin >> M [i] [j] ;
        }
    }

    {
    for ( int i = 1 ; i < n + 1 ; i++)
        for ( int j = 1 ; j < n + 1 ; j++)

            if ( M [i] [1] < M [i] [j] )
            {

            int INC = M [i] [j] ;
            }
        cout << "[" << i << "]" << "-r Mor inc tei" << endl ;       
    }
}
```

Comment: Array indexes start at zero. Change `for (int i=1; i<n+1; i++)` to `for (int i=0; i<n; i++)` (likewise for `j`).

Comment: `int M[n][n];` This is not standard C++. In C++ array dimensions must be compile-time constants.

Comment: is that always necessary  ? cuz it kinda worked o.O

Comment: You calculate the min of each row, not monotony. You should detail what you want exactly

Comment: yea , i thought that i should find min of each row then compare it to their next counterpart element. it didn't work out as i thought it would. i do need to find the monotony tho

Comment: You only need compare each element with previous one

Comment: err, how would that work? would i still need the bool part or do i do a simple comparison with if?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your last attempt, you did not correct the indices (starting at 0).
Moreover, the real test for monotony is between `j - 1` and `j` elements. Here is the corrected code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Kvadrat Matriciin irembiig oruulnuu:" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    int M [n] [n] ;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < n; i++) {
        for ( int j = 0 ; j < n; j++) {
            cout << "[" << i << "]" << "[" << j << "]" << " Bairshiltai Toog oruulnuu" << endl ;
            cin >> M [i] [j] ;
        }
    }

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < n  ; i++) {
        bool monotonic = true;
        for ( int j = 1 ; j < n; j++) {
            monotonic = monotonic && (M [i] [j-1] < M [i] [j]);
        }
        cout << "[" << i << "] : " << "monotonic = " << monotonic << "\n" ;       
    }
}
```

Comment: oooooh, now i see why having the indices start from 0 is better, thanks a lot :)